# in unity, animator transition from one animation to another will reset character position

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

see my gif

[image]

in my animator, "climb-to-top" > "stand", when transition enter "stand", character position will reset to transition start

when i try another climb-to-top2, see my gif, "climb-to-top2" > "stand" will make character stand on reached top

[image]

**I apply "climb-to-top" and "climb-to-top2" to same "apply root motion" character, why one reset position, one doesn't?**

update

climb-to-top is from [SD Unity-chan Adventure Action Pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/animations/sd-unity-chan-adventure-action-pack-62560) > climb_mount@unlock

climb-to-top2 is from [RPG Character Mecanim Animation Pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/animations/rpg-character-mecanim-animation-pack-63772) > Climb-Ladder-Off-Top

they are paid asset, sorry I cannot upload 2 animation files

update:

I ask the "SD Unity-chan Adventure Action Pack" author, it reply:

> Hi, roro codeath Thank you for purchasing Haon's package! And thank
>   you for letting us know the problem.
>
> The unlock motions are not Root motion. In-motion motion with Y-axis
>   elevation. Therefore, it is not a bug. Now, we are preparing Root
>   motion with package renewal. (An update is scheduled for December.)
>
> In some cases, changing the options for motion can solve the problem.
>   Please refer to the video below.
>   https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fxqrmgs13931uv/2018-10-31%2006-31-13-234.mp4?dl=0
>
> I hope your issue will be resolved in this way. Thank

in unity editor side, even i set Climb fbx root motion in fbx inspector > Animation > Motion > root motion node, this bug still exist, so maybe I should do some thing in maya

Comment: Have you tried applying "Root Motion"?

Comment: @bolkay yes, I "apply root motion", but I apply "climb-to-top" and "climb-to-top2" to same "apply root motion" character, why one reset position, one doesn't?

Comment: Interesting. So, you want the behaviour to be as shown in the second gif? If yes, I suspect there is a problem with the animation setup.

Comment: @bolkay I compare 2 animation FBX in unity inspector, I think their conf are same, so I'm confused, what cause the diff

Comment: It's a strange behaviour if you're right. You should also check the Root Transform Position settings, if you haven't.

Comment: I find the solution, I answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102543/6011193)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, I answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102543/6011193), in this anim fbx, the model skeleton has no root object(like unity gameobject center point) to determine transform position